# How can I insert a String of base64-encoded data into an sqlite3 table?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, base64

I am writing an android app. I have an String of base64-encoded data, and I want to store it in my sqlite3 table. I am trying to do the following:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = new MyDatabase(MyApplication.getContext()).getWritableDatabase();
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("insert into MyTable values($next_id, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
stmt.bindLong(1, id);
stmt.bindString(2, someString);
stmt.bindLong(3, someLong);
stmt.bindLong(4, anotherLong);
stmt.bindLong(5, moreLong);
stmt.bindString(6, base64Data); // the field in question
stmt.execute();
```

But I get this error:

```
(1299) abort at 19 in [insert into MyTable values($next_id, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);]: NOT NULL constraint failed: MyTable.base64Data
```

`MyTable.base64Data` schema is: `base64Data text NOT NULL`

I can see in my debugger that base64Data is not null, so I think my query must not be formed correctly.

I also tried putting the last question mark in quotes:

```
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("insert into MyTable values($next_id, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, \"?\");");
```

But that did not fix the error. What do I need to do?

Comment: Well *is* `base64Data` null? Have you tried with a small fixed sample base64 string?

Comment: @JonSkeet, If you are going to respond, please read my post. I have already said that "I can see in my debugger that base64Data is not null."

Comment: Ah, I missed that bit, sorry. Have you tried specifying the columns by name in the insert? Aside from anything else, that would make the insert less brittle... and if it turns out that your schema doesn't have that column in the place you expect, that would explain the error. (I'd also try to reproduce this in as short an example as possible - start cutting parts of your schema etc until you've got a completely minimal example.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, Thanks, I have not tried that. I think I've just figured it out though. When I used single quotes instead of double quotes, I got an error on a different field, so I may have fixed this particular error.

Comment: No, that hasn't fixed the error - that will just treat the question mark as a literal rather than as a parameter - you'll end up with `"?"` in the text field, not the value you want.

Comment: @JonSkeet, you are correct. It caused my base64Data to be stored in a different field... a field that was declared as `int NOT NULL`.. I am very confused.

Comment: No need to be confused - you were no longer using that parameter for that field, so it was in the next field instead. You don't want to use `'?'` here.

Comment: Can you use the debugger to post the actual SQL that generates the error?

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand why it would put the data in another field, but I expected there to be an error since the field is for `int` data.

Comment: @StanSmith, Good idea. I will try to capture the actual query in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have seven parameters, but bind only six.

(If the first column should be autoincrementing, use NULL instead of `$next_id`.)

Comment: The first column is autoincrementing, and $next_id seems to work fine with it. Is there really a difference?

Comment: Wow, that actually fixed my entire problem. Changing `$next_id` to `null` made everything work. Apparently, `$next_id` was being regarded as nothing (zero characters), so everything was shifted over, leaving my last field empty (hence the `NOT NULL constraint failed`). Thanks!

Comment: `$xxx` is a parameter just like `?`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I read somewhere else that `$next_id` was the correct thing to use, and it worked when I typed it into my sqlite command line, but not via `compileStatement()`.